# Calculator dont get a result when i click =

Tags: xamarin

[image]

im at the end of my first Xamarin Project but when im want a answer to a mathematic operation i get an error as Xamarin.Forms.Label

Maybe it has to do with the xaml file and the part for the OnCalculate Eventhandler in the xaml is as follows:

```
<Button Text="="
           Grid.Row="5"
           Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           TextColor="Black"
           FontSize="36" BorderRadius="0"
           Clicked="OnCalculate" />
```

...
And the .cs as follows:

```
void OnCalculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentState == 2)
        {
            var result = OperatorHelper.Calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber, myoperator);
            this.resultText.Text = resultText.ToString();
            firstNumber = result;
            currentState = -1;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

...

Comment: "i get an error" - this is not a helpful description of the problem.  Is it a compiler error or a runtime exception?  What is the **exact** error message?  Which line causes it?

Comment: I dont know my program doesnt have any error in visual Studio but when i run it on my phone after i do a mathematical operation and click the = Button i get no result but the Xamarin.Forms.Label on my Resulttext

Comment: what is `resultText`?  Is that an element defined in your XAML?  `this.resultText.Text = resultText.ToString();` shouldn't this be  `this.resultText.Text = result.ToString();`?

Comment: Yes its defined as resulttext<Label
            x:Name="resultText"
            FontSize="48"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            Text="0"
            TextColor="White"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing this

```
var result = OperatorHelper.Calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber, myoperator);
this.resultText.Text = resultText.ToString();
```

when you probably want to do this (show the value of `result` in your output)

```
var result = OperatorHelper.Calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber, myoperator);
this.resultText.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks its working very nicely but ist it possible change it that it shows the complete mathematical operation as like value1 + value2 = sum for example ?

Comment: `this.resultText.Text = $"{firstNumber} {myoperator} {secondNumber} = {result}";`